# How to use camera flash in gpuImageView

Tags: android, android-camera, gpuimage

https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

I know how to turn on and off camera flash but the gpuImage preview is not showing flash even if I an turning it on during capture() process of gpuImageView. Any help would be appreciated.